# Custom Actions all document libraries

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, custom-actions

I want to develop a "Custom Action" for all of document libraries in a site collection, I tried looking on Google but couldn't find any relevent tutorial.

Custom action has to be in "Actions" and below "Export to spreadsheet".

**Edit**

I got custom Document libraries as well as out of box ones and since I don't want to relate this action to lists I will have to find out what can I use for "RegistrationType", "RegistrationID" and "Location"

For a normal list its something like this,

```
 Location="EditControlBlock"
 RegistrationId="11000"
 RegistrationType="List"
```

**but not sure what would be location for this "actions" and whether I can do something to relate it to all document libraries out of box or custom ones**

**Edit 2**

I find what I was looking for here

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/sharepoint-2010-extend-document-library.html

however still not sure if it will work for custom document libraries or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with this is you are running 2007, I have no idea.

But 2010..

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

Someone has a good example of a custom action in the comments, can't test myself for 2k7 but you never know. Never had need to until 2010.

HTH

Comment: cheers, it does work on 2007 as well but there are few requirements I need to follow.

Comment: Awesome post your results.